# How can I migrate an Google App Engine Flex app to Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I'd like to convert my Google App Engine Flask WSGI application to a Google Compute Engine one, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I'm running the Geneplore API https://docs.geneplore.com if that helps.